# Test Data showing 100% accuracy

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
df_concat = shuffle(df_concat)
df = df_concat

X = df.loc[:, df.columns != 'NEWACCT_NO']
X = X.loc[:, X.columns != 'CURRENT_MTH_CHURN']
X = X.values
y = df.CURRENT_MTH_CHURN.values # Target variable


from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.33, random_state = 1)

#Train the model with the help of DecisionTreeClassifie
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight="balanced")
clf = clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

#At last we need to make prediction. It can be done with the help of following script −
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)


#Next, we can get the accuracy score, confusion matrix and classification report as follows −
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, accuracy_score
result = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print("Confusion Matrix:")
print(result)
result1 = classification_report(y_test, y_pred)
print("Classification Report:",)
print (result1)
result2 = accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)
print("Accuracy:",result2)
```

Output:

```
Confusion Matrix:
[[8238    0]
 [   0 1066]]
Classification Report:
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      1.00      1.00      8238
           1       1.00      1.00      1.00      1066

    accuracy                           1.00      9304
   macro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00      9304
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00      9304

Accuracy: 1.0
```

Even though train_test_split is dividing the training & test data randomly, apart from that, i have also used sklearn.utils shuffle, but still i am getting 100% accuracy on test data.

Not able to identify the mistake.

Also, tried removing class_weight="balanced" parameter, but the results are same.

Experts advice required please.

Comment: You have perfect results, what are you complaining about?

Comment: Have you tried with a different random_state to see if you always get 100% accuracy? Otherwise the common explanation with 100% accuracy is that you have used as a feature something that is directly linked to your target and that you were not supposed to use

Comment: In most real-world scenarios, 100% accuracy on hold-out set does not mean results are perfect, it means there's a bug. I think this is a wise (albeit not mcve) question

Answer (score 4):

you're splitting your data into train and test but apparently all your feature generation was already done upstream of this code. So if any of your feature-generation code involves using your dependent variable in any way (e.g. a var like `mean_churn_per_account_type` or something), that means your train-set features incorporate information from your test set's dependent variable. This is known in ML as a "data leak" - you leaked test-set data into your train-set via features you created before train test split.

To fix this, you need to move your train-test split upstream of any feature-generation steps that involve your dependent variable. Applying your feature-generation steps identically to train and test set can lead to trip-ups - but using an [sklearn pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) will help.

Disclaimer: this is all speculation since we can't actually see your feature-generation code. But in my experience this is the most likely source.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, as suggested, I checked the correlation matrix, and got to know that there was a variable named "IMAGE" which was having -0.86 correlation with the CHURN variable.

Once i removed it, was able to achieve a satisfactory result:

```
print(classification_report(test_output_smote, test_prediction_upsampled_smote))
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           N       0.74      0.84      0.79      8233
           Y       0.81      0.71      0.76      8233

    accuracy                           0.78     16466
   macro avg       0.78      0.78      0.77     16466
weighted avg       0.78      0.78      0.77     16466
```

Thanks, everyone for your help & support.